# Python Package Correct Import Structure For Source And Binaries?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, python-packaging

*I want to start by saying I know this has been answered many times before, but there was a lot of conflicting answers and half-solutions*

### Summary of layout

EDIT: [GitHub Link Here](https://github.com/Cornelius-Figgle/ROSA)

I am making a program valled `ROSA` in Python, and wish for it to be usable both by **directly running a single script** and by **importing** the code so that a user can write their own wrapper for it. Consequently, I have split the program into 2 files (well actually 3, but)

- the file `ROSA.py` which contains a class called `ROSA_` and uses class attributes from the `foreign_potato_master.py` file. Running this file directly does nothing
- the file `main.py` which is imports `ROSA.py` and uses the `ROSA_` class (it also uses variables from `ROSA.py` to decide whether the script is on a Raspberry Pi or a desktop, etc). This file is made to be run directly, and basically just calls the functions from `ROSA_`
- the file `foreign_potato_master.py` which contains a few classes that contain dictionaries of strings that are used by `ROSA.py` to reply to the user. I moved these into a separate file to make it easier for others to edit the output of my program

### Brief file contents:

###### ROSA.py:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import foreign_potato_master

try: 
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  # type: ignore
    is_on_RPi = True
except ImportError:
    # note: Probably a more elegant solution somewhere
    # note: but this is what works for me atm
    is_on_RPi = False

class ROSA_:
    def __init__(self, json_path = None):
        ...

        self.title = foreign_potato_master.Text_Decorations.title
        self.symbols = foreign_potato_master.Text_Decorations.symbols

        self.activations = foreign_potato_master.Responses.activations
        self.keys = foreign_potato_master.Responses.keys
        self.responses = foreign_potato_master.Responses.responses
        self.prev_responses = foreign_potato_master.Responses.prev_responses

        ...

    def background_listening(self):
        ...
```

###### foreign_potato_master.py:

```py
class Responses:
    activations = [...] 
    keys = {...}
    responses = {...}
    prev_responses = {...}

class Text_Decorations:
    title = '...'
    symbols = {...}

...
```

###### main.py:

```py
import ROSA

def main():
    ...

    obj = ROSA.ROSA_()
    speech = obj.background_listening()

    ...

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

###### **init**.py:

```py
from ROSA import ROSA
from ROSA import foreign_potato_master
```

**all of the files have some comments/docstrings/verison tags etc in the top, including the `__init__.py`**

### Directory Structure

```
ROSA
|- bin
    |- ...
|- docs
    |- ...
|- src
    |- ROSA
        |- __init__.py
        |- foreign_potato_master.py
        |- gpio.json
        |- main.py
        |- ROSA.py
```

### My question:

What is the best way to import these files into each other?

```py
# main.py
from . import ROSA
import .ROSA
```

Both of the above fail (`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` and `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` respectively)

```py
# main.py
import ROSA
```

The above works when running as Python files, but not as compiled binaries (via `pyinstaller`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\192.168.0.8\source\projects\ROSA\src\ROSA\main.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "ROSA\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "ROSA\ROSA.py", line 80, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foreign_potato_master'
[2520] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

*the above was run in Windows Sandbox*

EDIT: probably should have clarified, the exe was built using the following batch script:

```
:: \ROSA

pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=WARN --clean ^
    --distpath ".\bin\bin" --workpath ".\bin\build" ^
    --name ROSA --onefile ^
    --paths ".\rosa-env\Lib\site-packages" ^
    --hidden-import pyi_splash ^
    --add-binary ".\src\ROSA\responses;.\responses" ^
    --splash ".\docs\ico\hotpot-ai.png" --icon ".\docs\ico\hotpot-ai.ico" ^
    .\src\ROSA\main.py
```

#### Finally (TL;DR):

So how can I import these files and have it work when run directly, when imported and when compiled to binary?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your setup, and it isn't clear why you would be having import errors.  Do you have this project in an open repository somewhere?

Comment: Yes will add github link now

Comment: Where you wrote `from . import ROSA` I would expect to see `from .src import ROSA`. That's assuming you're chdir'd to repo toplevel, and the PYTHONPATH env var contains `.` dot. Use `$ python -m site` to help understand what's happening with `sys.path`, the variable that controls how `import` behaves.

Comment: So after working with it for a little more I must have changed your folder structure along with the other modifications to make it work and then forgot about it. So when we discussed making the edits for the json file I started over again with a fresh clone and couldn't get it to work again

Comment: hmmmm weird - I thought folder struct was standard so idk why there is problems

Comment: @J_H, sorry for long reply I think I missed the notification, and I was running scripts from the project repo root (ie the first ROSA folder)